# Gaussian Mixture Model of Solar Data(Power in kW)

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, model, beta-distribution, mixture-distribution

Gaussian Mixture Model in Matlab( More likely that it will be a combination of 2 normal distribution or Beta distribution)
Let's say I have a collection of data that I want to model using Probability distributions. I'll call my data "yearly_data" and a frequency distribution is attached below and as it can be seen, it has 2 peaks therefore it cannot be modelled using a single Gaussian so it has to be a Gaussian mixture model. I want to be able to fit and produce a PDF of the model. How can I do this? I am more interested in how this is done in Matlab so if you can't help with Matlab then don't answer the question. Explanation of theory behind it will also be useful. Please provide a sample code
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this 
https://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/gmdistribution-class.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

and this explanation

https://youtu.be/Rkl30Fr2S38